# Find line-by-line difference using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have realized line-by-line comparison of 2 text files in plain old style:

```
string[] linesOld = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, oldFileName));
string[] linesNew = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, newFileName));

for (int i = 1; i < linesNew.Length; i++)
{
    if (linesNew[i] != linesOld[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Line: {0}, Old: {1}, New: {2}", i, linesOld[i], linesNew[i]);
    }
}
```

How can I rewrite this code in new LINQ style?

May be should I use

```
linesNew.Except(linesOld);
```

?

Comment: *Why* do you want to use LINQ for this? The original code looks clear enough to me, apart from problems if `linesNew.Length != linesOld.Length`, but that's more of a specification problem.

Comment: There isn't really anything clearer about 5 lines when it can be done in around 20 characters, more maintainably.

Comment: Just for fun - I learn LINQ! P.S. Yes, I know KISS principle ;-)

Comment: There's also the matter of LINQ being part of the framework and therefore being a good tool to use, and the fact that *what* is a better abstraction than *how*. Really, this is a perfect time for LINQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
int i = 1;
foreach (var lines in linesOld.Zip(linesNew, (oldLine, newLine) =>
 new { oldLine, newLine, lineNumber = i++ }).Where(x => x.oldLine != x.newLine))
    Console.WriteLine("Line: {0}, Old: {1}, New: {2}",
                      lines.lineNumber, lines.oldLine, lines.newLine);
```

Comment: @hellboy could then make an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) out of (his to get what he wants.